# How do I segue from a storyboard automatically by giving it a time limit.

Tags: ios, swift, segue, appdelegate

I created a new View Controller to act as LaunchScreenController. In my appDelegate I set my LaunchScreenViewController to occupy 0.0 time, this is because I want my launch screen to be dynamic. I would like to then transition from the fake launchScreen to my Main after 5 seconds that my fakeLaunchScreen runs. How would I do this in the appDelegate?

Comment: Don't do it in your AppDelegate. Implement a custom view controller for your launch screen and start a timer in its `viewDidAppear`. When the timer fires call `performSegue` to segue to your main view comtroller

Comment: Even easier would be to use dispatch_after. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861